# Implicit nonlinear regressions in R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I am trying to estimate the parameters of the following nonlinear model in implicit form:
its expression is not given by y = f(x;theta) + u
but by u = g(x,y;theta)
with u the random term, x and y are the explanatory and explained variable. It is not possible to obtain f from g (as g cannot be inverted in y and/or g is not additive in u).
Both NLS and GMM below do not run. 
I could not find anything about this issue in the NLS and GMM documentation, so I wonder how to do it. I would appreciate any help on this topic.

More specifically, I considered the following specification for g (but NLS and GMM do not run):

```
#
# The DGP
#
set.seed(34567)
N <- 1000 # sample size
x <- rnorm(N) # explanatory variable
u <- rnorm(N) # u is the random term or the model
y <- (81 - 3*x*x)*(1+exp(u)) # y = h(x,u;theta) is the explained variable
summary(y)
#
# The NLS regression: we know that the true functional form is u = g(x,y;theta) and E[u]=0 
# but we do not know that the DGP is obtained for theta_0=81 and theta_1=3 
#
x2 <- x*x
NLS_reg <- function(theta_0, theta_1) {
  log( y / (theta_0 - theta_1*x2) - 1 ) 
}
nls_out <- nls(0 ~ NLS_reg(theta_0, theta_1), start = list(theta_0 = 84.3, theta_1 = 3.25), trace = T)
summary(nls_out)
#
# The GMM regression
#
require("gmm")
iota <- rep(1,N)
data <- data.matrix(cbind(y, iota, x, x2))
GMM_reg <- function(data, theta_0, theta_1) {
  y <- as.numeric(data[,1])
  x2 <- as.numeric(data[,4])
  return( log( y / (theta_0*iota-theta_1*x2) - 1 ) )
}
moments <- function(data, theta_0, theta_1) {
  z <- data.matrix(data[, 2:4])
  m <- z * as.vector(GMM_reg(data, theta_0, theta_1))
  return(cbind(m))
}
GMM_out <- gmm(g=moments, x = data, t0 = c(78,2.6), type = "iterative", crit = 1e-3, wmatrix = "optimal", method = "Nelder-Mead", control = list(reltol = 1e-3, maxit = 100))
summary(GMM_out)
```

Comment: I ran your code, at least the NLS part. The error is pretty self-explanatory `parameters without starting value in 'data': alpha_0, alpha_1`. Just set some starting values for those parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Indeed my error was unfortunate, My apologies. B.